# How to monitor php variables?

Tags: php, php-extension

When I debug php program, I often use the function `var_dump()` to monitor the changes of variables' values to find out where the unexpected thing happens. This needs a lot of sentences and is certainly not a formal way to do this. IDEs like Zend Studio can do this, but I prefer the simpler way like `var_dump()`. I think there may be an extension can do this, which could be used to monitor the appointed variables and show all of the changes of their values. But I cannot find it by my effort, so could you help me?Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I've always been happy with "echo" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use http://xdebug.org. It's free and it's able to display of stack traces on error conditions, as a profiler, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will research it and determine whether it is exactly what I need.